# Whether it is possible to connect Mac Mini to the Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac-mini, remote-desktop

Will it be possible to connect the Mac Mini to the MacBook Pro and use the laptop's screen, keyboard for working on Mac Mini?

Comment: Do you mean *physically* like an iMac in  [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) or *virtually* like in screen sharing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the screen sharing that Allan mentioned is the only way. [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) is one of those apps that Is meant for this. Note that if you have an iPad, they work extremely well as a secondary screen with a mac, if the screen size is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Physically through a HDMI cable this isn't possible.

The MacBook Pro cannot take display input, only output.

This goes for any HDMI devices, not just a Mac Mini. You couldn't run a PS4 on your MBP screen for example.

The only way it might be possible is by sharing the screen in a method such as [this](https://www.macworld.com/article/2839080/away-from-home-heres-how-to-access-your-mac-remotely.html).

Comment: thank you. So my understanding on " Sharing the Screen  " - means : We will have to remote log in to the Mac Mini. There will not be any physical wire based connection involved between laptop and Mac Mini. Is that right ?

Comment: Yeah that's it basically. I'm not 100% sure on how you would do it as I have never done it myself. Just wanted to point out that it can't be done as simply as connecting them via HDMI. Hope that helps somewhat :)

Answer (score 1):

I connect from my 15” macbookpro to my mac mini via connect to server & sharescreen, then do all that is necessary : install software, play videos via iTunes which are then shown on the Samsung tv via hdmi from the mac mini - then log out leaving iTunes and the video playing fine...

No special third party software needed - all native by apple...

Comment: woow !! Thats interesting. Whether both devices are connected in wireless mode or any cables required to connect both the device

Comment: My Macbook has only 128GB and i am considering to buy a  Mac Mini which has either 500 GB or 1 TB.  But i dont want to buy Monitor /Keyboard. If i have the complete details on connecting from Macbook to Mac Mini, that will be very helpful ..

Comment: Macbook and mac mini communicate over the wireless network - no cables between them at all.